# How to send an option hash to sidekiq/activejob?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I'm trying to send options to a sidekiq worker. Sidekiq is using Activejob

```
class User 
  def do_background_task(object, options={})
    MyJob.perform_later(id, object.id, options )
  end
end

class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user_id,object_id,options={})
    user   = User.find(user_id)
    object = Object.find(user_id)
    selector = options[:selector] if options[:type]
    do some things....
    if selector == 'true'
      do some other things.....
    end 
  end
end
```

This is not working, and seems to be because either ActiveJob or Sidekiq does not like to receive a keyed hash. So e.g., `@user.do_background_task(@object, selector: true)` causes an error `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`.

What is the accepted way to pass keys to a queue?

Comment: Have you tried a hash keyed with strings instead? I've had a similar problem with Que, that was due to JSON serialization.

Comment: Thanks @D-side, yes I have tried `"selector" => "true"` but this also is not passed correctly

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of Rails 4.2.  AJ serialization has seen some bug fixes.